# Is there any way I can restart my computer from within a Python program and then resume execution from the point it left off at?

Tags: python

I am using an Ubuntu VM on my Macbook Air (using VMWare Fusion). My objective is to run a few tasks in a Python program, restarting my VM, and then resume execution of the program from where it left off. I am able to restart the VM perfectly, but the second part of my problem is where I have an issue.

For example:

```py
import time as t
import os

print("1")
t.sleep(2)
print("2")
t.sleep(2)
print("3")
t.sleep(2)
print("4")
t.sleep(2)
print("5")
t.sleep(2)

print("Restarting now")
t.sleep(4)
os.system("shutdown -r now")

print("6")
t.sleep(2)
print("7")
t.sleep(2)
print("8")
t.sleep(2)
print("9")
t.sleep(2)
print("10")
t.sleep(2)
```

The output obtained when I run the code is simply

```
1 
2
3
4
5

Restarting now
```

I want to resume execution upon restart from the `print("6")` statement.

Comment: Have you ever heard of entities called `files`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should write down the last value into a `file`, then check that file whenever you run the script again.

```py
#...
last_point = ''
if os.path.exist("last_point"):
    last_point = open("last_point", 'r').read()
if not last_point:
    do_part1()
    #...
    open("last_point", 'w').write("5")
    os.system("shutdown -r now")
else:
    do_part2()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using something like Docker, I believe you can pause the container and then resume it after you reboot.

Otherwise it's still possible, but you'd have to reorganize the program to record its current progress in a file, check that file when it starts up, and add the capability to jump to any later point in the code based on what was in the file.

Comment: I edited my question: I am using VMWare. I did think of files, but I couldn't really find how I can save the "current progress". How does that work?